# write permutations of 0 and 1

Tags: binary, permutation, pascal

I need to make program in pascal.

for example

```
readln(4)
```

and output should be all permutations of 0 and 1

`0000
 0001
 0010
 0100
 0111
 0011
 0110
 0101
 1010
 1000
 1001
 1100
 1011
 1101
 1110
 1111`

Could you help me please?

Comment: I'm quite certain that your instructor wants to see your work and not ours. If you can't get started on your assignment, ask your instructor for help; either they've not yet earned their pay for providing you an education, or you've not been attentive in class.

Comment: Sorry I didn't want you do my homework. I asked you for help, cause when I ask my teacher for help his respon is "try to think like the program" and it is not food hunt for me

Comment: Sorry. We're not here to do your homework, as I said. Your teacher is **being paid to educate you**. If you don't understand the information well enough to start your assignment, **ask your instructor again** for help.

Comment: It's very unclear from your question how much Pascal you know. This website isn't about teaching people a programming language from scratch. The assumption is that you have learned to a certain point and you've tried something but having trouble getting it working or stuck on what that "next step" is. The only Pascal you show in your question is `readln(4)` which is not valid. You need at least to start with a proper program structure. If you're not sure what a valid Pascal program looks like, you'll need to look at a book or read a tutorial. But I assume it's taught in your class.

Answer (score -1):

You may have noticed that "All the permutations of 0 and 1" are the [binary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number).

Given the input 3, you would output this:

```
000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110 and  111
```

and they are the numbers `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6` and `7` in base 2 (binary).

So you have 2 problems here.

First, you need to be able to convert a Decimal (base 10) integer (e.g. 12) into binary (12 in binary is 1100).

And the second issue is working out where to stop with the integers. If you are given the input `2` then you will output `00, 10, 11` and stop. That's from 0 to 3. Given `3` you output `000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111` - that's from 0 to 7.

Is there a pattern here? Yes. Try to find a way to work out what the maximum Decimal number will be if your input is X.

> Base 10 works in powers of 10, `100 10 1`
>  Base 2 is powers of 2, `4  2  1`
>  So given the input 5, we know that there will be 5 `1`s as the last number, `11111`. What is this number in decimal? It is 2<sup>5</sup> -1, which is 31. Given the input 3, we know it will be `111` which is 7, or 2<sup>3</sup> -1
>  
>  So given any input X, we know that the last number will be X `1`s in a row, and that X `1`s will equal 2<sup>X</sup> -1
>  
>  This is simple to program. Simply create a function `MagicForumulaForCalculatingNumberGivenLength` which takes an integer as input (the length) and returns the decimal integer:
>  
>  
>  `function MagicForumulaForCalculatingNumberGivenLength(input:integer):integer;
>      Result := (power(2, input) -1);`

So, now we know the Decimal number we need to go up to - for an input of 5 it is 31.

I assume you can loop like this:

```
readln(Input);

for I := 1 to MagicFormulaForCalculatingNumberGivenLength(Input);
    writeln(MagicFormulaForCalculatingBinaryGivenNumber(I));
```

So now the only issue is how to create the binary number. [It's pretty easy](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/zAppendixH/appH_4.html) - I'll give you the code in Pseudo Code so you can write it yourself into pascal:

```
define DecimalNumberToBinaryString(Input:integer):string;

  SBinary: string;
  SBinaryRev: string;


  while Input > 0 do
    SBinary = SBinary + mod(Input,2)
    Input = div(Input,2)

 SBinaryRev = TextReverse(SBinary);

 return SBinary
```

Comment: If I've made a mistake, please comment. This is my first Pascal answer, I'm newish to the language.